How can I paginate by month in vue.js?
I write a project in django and vue.js. In vue.js I have this:
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-6 mb-3" v-for="object in personWorkingScheduleData" :key="object.id">
       <div class="card mb-5 h-100" style="border:1px solid  #eff2f7;  padding: 12px; height: 300px;">
         <div class="card-body">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-3">
               <div class="text-lg-center">
                 <div class="mt-3">
                   <label>Night time</label>
                   <b-form-checkbox :checked="object.is_night_shift" @input="object.is_night_shift = $event"
                  :disabled="!object.can_change" class="mb-3 custom-checkbox" plain></b-form-checkbox>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div>
              <div class="mt-3">
                <label>Days</label>
                <multiselect :disabled="!object.can_change" required :options="weekdayOptions"
                  :value="extractWeekdays(object.weekdays)" track-by="id" label="weekday" multiple
                  placeholder="Choose days" selectLabel="Choose day" selectedLabel="selected"
                   :max-height="200" @input="handleMultiselectChange($event, object)">
                </multiselect>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                  <li class="list-inline-item me-3">
                    <h5
                          class="font-size-14"
                          data-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-placement="top"
                          title="From"
                        >
                        <label class="mt-3">From*</label><br>
                        <i class="bx bx-calendar me-1 text-muted">
                          <b-form-input class="no-border" :value="object.start_date" :disabled="!object.can_change" @input="object.start_date = $event"
                          id="example-input" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" autocomplete="off"></b-form-input>
                        </i>
                      </h5>
                      
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item me-3">
                    <h5
                          class="font-size-14"
                          data-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-placement="top"
                          title="To"
                        >
                        <label class="mt-3">To*</label><br>
                        <i class="bx bx-calendar me-1 text-muted">
                          <b-form-input class="no-border" :value="object.end_date" :disabled="!object.can_change" @input="object.end_date = $event"
                          id="example-input" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" autocomplete="off"></b-form-input>
                        </i>
                      </h5>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-inline mb-0" v-if="object.start_time && object.end_time">
                <li class="list-inline-item me-3">
                  <h5
                        class="font-size-14"
                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-placement="top"
                        title="From"
                      >
                      <label>Start time</label>
                      <br />
                      <i class="bx bx-time me-1 text-muted">
                        <b-form-input class="no-border" :value="object.start_time" :disabled="!object.can_change" @input="object.start_time = $event"
                        format="HH:mm" value-type="format" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm"></b-form-input>
                      </i></h5>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item me-3">
                  <h5
                        class="font-size-14"
                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-placement="top"
                        title="From"
                      >
                      <label>End time</label>
                    <br />
                    <i class="bx bx-time me-1 text-muted">
                      <b-form-input class="no-border" :value="object.end_time" :disabled="!object.can_change" @input="object.end_time = $event"
                      format="HH:mm" value-type="format" type="time" placeholder="hh:mm"></b-form-input>
                    </i></h5>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And in django I wrote a month pagination
class MonthlyPagination(PageNumberPagination):
page_size = 10

def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    self.months = {}
    for item in queryset:
        month_year = item.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m")
        if month_year not in self.months:
            self.months[month_year] = [item]
        else:
            self.months[month_year].append(item)

    page_number = request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, 1)
    self.page = page_number
    return self.months.get(page_number, [])

def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    next_page_number = int(self.page) + 1 if int(self.page) < len(self.months) else None
    prev_page_number = int(self.page) - 1 if int(self.page) > 1 else None

    return Response({
        'links': {
            'next': next_page_number,
            'previous': prev_page_number
        },
        'count': sum(len(month) for month in self.months.values()),
        'total_pages': len(self.months),
        'current_page': int(self.page),
        'results': data  
    })

but it didn't work. How can I paginate records by months? I don't care how many records have its month I just want to paginate them by month and year. For examble the records of May 2024 to be in different page with records of June 2024.

There is quite a lot of code here. What does not work exactly? Can you use Postman and be able to have paginated data while reaching a specific endpoint?

it is an uncompleted question,   no  pagination componts code or description at all.

I use b-pagination but I don't know if I should use this for month pagination

Is your backend working well so far?

Yes in other paginations but not in month pagination

Fix the month pagination first then, it is not a UI issue. What are you using btw, Bootstrap?

I use b-pagination in vue.js

As in? b-pagination is not a native thing to VueJS.
